# How to open an email attachment using html

Tags: html, css

I want to open a attached .html in a mail using html.

I have a responsive html email and added there a link to open it in a browser. But instead of hosting the email on a server I have the same .html attached to the mail.

Is there a way to link it directly to the attachment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a mail client that is capable to act like a web browser. one is an email client, one is a browser both with special abilities. 
using thunderbird/outlook/... as a web browser simply is not meant to be. although you could access your mailserver with a browser ...